# Excel 'Match' returning #N/A until 'Enter' is clicked inside relevant cell, then it returns the correct match value

Tags: excel

### What I have tried:

I have 3 columns. In column A I have a long list of numbers I'd like to search in, in column B I have a few numbers I'd like to look up inside of column A, and in cell C1 I have the formula "=MATCH(B1,A:A,0)" written inside. Both columns A and B are 'number' formats and calculations are set to automatic.

```
   A      B      C
 1 16.58  13.56  2
 2 13.56  10.12  #N/A
 3 11.18  16.58  1
 4 10.12  12.02  ..
 ..     ..
```

### My problem:

My problem is that some cells return #N/A (e.g. above where cell C2 should be returning 4). However, if I click into the cell B2 then hit 'Enter' it all of a sudden works (C2 spits out the correct value of 4).

How can I fix this annoying issue?

Comment: Just a thought - put 1 in a new cell, copy it, and then paste special > multiply on all the cells in columns A and B.

Comment: What is the format of column C ?

Comment: Hi BigBen, I just tried that but unfortunately it didn't change the result

Comment: Mikku, column C is also in number format